# Moving row values between columns based on other column values in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with a list of organism names and their antibiotic sensitivities. I wish to consolidate all organisms into one column, in the DataFrame below, based on the following rules.

1. If ORG1 == A, do nothing;
2. If ORG1 != A and ORG2 == A, move ORG2 values into ORG1 column
3. If ORG1 != A and ORG3 == A, move ORG3 values into ORG1 column

If condition 2 is met, as well as moving ORG2 value to ORG1 column, also move column values in AS20* into AS10*.

Similarly, if condition 3 is met, as well as moving ORG3 value to ORG1 column, also move column values in AS30* into AS10*.

I tried this myself by writing a function based on the rules above and had limited success based on the following:

```
If ORG2 == A:
       return ORG1.map(ORG2)
```

I got lost when I tried to sequentially map AS201 -> AS101, AS202 -> AS102, AS203 -> AS103 etc. based on the condition.

The other issue I have is that the organism names are not single letters, neither are the pretty. A in the example is equivalent to `re.match('aureus')` in my dataset.

Also, there are 20 AS columns for every ORG column and in excess of 150,000 records so I hope to make it generalizable for any number of antibiotic sensitivity results.

I am struggling a bit with it so a couple of shoves in the right direction would really help.

Thanks in advance.

```
Index   ORG1    ORG2    ORG3    AB1    AS101    AS201   AS301     AB2   AS102   AS202 AS302
1          A     NaN     NaN    pen        S      NaN     NaN   dfluc       S     NaN   NaN
2          A       B       C    pen        R        S       S   dfluc       S       R     S
3          B       A       B    pen        S        S       R   dfluc       S       S     R
4          A     NaN     NaN    pen        R      NaN     NaN   dfluc       S     NaN   NaN
5          A     NaN     NaN    pen        R      NaN     NaN   dfluc       S     NaN   NaN
6          C       A       A    pen        S        R       R   dfluc       R       S     R
7          B     NaN       A    pen        R      NaN       S   dfluc       S     NaN     S
8          A       B       A    pen        R        R       R   dfluc       R       R     R
9          A     NaN     NaN    pen        R      NaN     NaN   dfluc       S     NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could select rows where `ORG1 != A` and `ORG2 == A` with

```
mask = (df['ORG1'] != 'A')&(df[orgi] == 'A')
```

`mask` is then a boolean Series. To copy values from ORG2 to ORG1, we could then use

```
df['ORG1'][mask] = df['ORG2'][mask]
```

or, since we know the value on the right is `A`, we could just use

```
df['ORG1'][mask] = 'A'
```

Copying the AS columns can be done similarly.

---

We can find rows whose column value contains some string like `'aureus'` with

```
df[orgi].str.contains('aureus') == True
```

`str.contains` can take **any regex** pattern as its argument.
See the docs: [Vectorized String Methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods).

Note: Usually it would be enough to use `df[orgi].str.contains('aureus')` (without the `== True`, but since `df[orgi]` might contain `NaN` values, we need to also map the `NaN`s to False, so we use `df[orgi].str.contains('aureus') == True`.

---

```
import pandas as pd

filename = 'data.txt'
df = pd.read_table(filename, delimiter='\s+')
print(df)
#    Index ORG1 ORG2 ORG3  AB1 AS101 AS201 AS301    AB2 AS102 AS202 AS302
# 0      1    A  NaN  NaN  pen     S   NaN   NaN  dfluc     S   NaN   NaN
# 1      2    A    B    C  pen     R     S     S  dfluc     S     R     S
# 2      3    B    A    B  pen     S     S     R  dfluc     S     S     R
# 3      4    A  NaN  NaN  pen     R   NaN   NaN  dfluc     S   NaN   NaN
# 4      5    A  NaN  NaN  pen     R   NaN   NaN  dfluc     S   NaN   NaN
# 5      6    C    A    A  pen     S     R     R  dfluc     R     S     R
# 6      7    B  NaN    A  pen     R   NaN     S  dfluc     S   NaN     S
# 7      8    A    B    A  pen     R     R     R  dfluc     R     R     R
# 8      9    A  NaN  NaN  pen     R   NaN   NaN  dfluc     S   NaN   NaN

for i in range(2,4):
    orgi = 'ORG{i}'.format(i=i)
    # mask = (df['ORG1'] != 'A')&(df[orgi] == 'A')
    mask = (df['ORG1'].str.contains('A') == False)&(df[orgi].str.contains('A') == True)
    # Move ORGi --> ORG1
    df['ORG1'][mask] = df[orgi][mask]
    for j in range(1,4):
        # Move ASij --> AS1j
        source_as = 'AS{i}{j:02d}'.format(i=i, j=j)
        target_as = 'AS1{j:02d}'.format(i=i, j=j)
        try:
            df[target_as][mask] = df[source_as][mask]
        except KeyError:
            pass

print(df)
```

yields

```
   Index ORG1 ORG2 ORG3  AB1 AS101 AS201 AS301    AB2 AS102 AS202 AS302
0      1    A  NaN  NaN  pen     S   NaN   NaN  dfluc     S   NaN   NaN
1      2    A    B    C  pen     R     S     S  dfluc     S     R     S
2      3    A    A    B  pen     S     S     R  dfluc     S     S     R
3      4    A  NaN  NaN  pen     R   NaN   NaN  dfluc     S   NaN   NaN
4      5    A  NaN  NaN  pen     R   NaN   NaN  dfluc     S   NaN   NaN
5      6    A    A    A  pen     R     R     R  dfluc     S     S     R
6      7    A  NaN    A  pen     S   NaN     S  dfluc     S   NaN     S
7      8    A    B    A  pen     R     R     R  dfluc     R     R     R
8      9    A  NaN  NaN  pen     R   NaN   NaN  dfluc     S   NaN   NaN
```

Note that if `ORG2 == A` and `ORG3 == A`, then values in column `AS20*` and `AS30*` both compete to overwrite values in column `AS10*`. I'm not sure which value you want to win. In the code above, the *last* column wins, which would be `AS30*`.

Comment: Thanks @unutbu, this looks wonderful. Rather than `mask = (df['ORG1'] != 'A')&(df[orgi] == 'A')`, how would I mask with a regular expression on ORG1 and orgi in the mask? I tried `mask = (re.search('aureus', x) != None for x in df.ORG1 ) & (re.search('aureus', x) != None for x in df[orgi] )` and got nowhere

Comment: I added a bit on how to do regex search on columns with string values.

Comment: thanks so much. This is huge. I added an update to move the organism name across to ORG1 column if the pattern matched. I have no preference which columns wins if ORG2 and ORG3 are matched. The chances are slim (very) and either way I still get the organism I want consolidated into one column.