# Copy row value to adjacent column based on value in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with two columns, A and B, which contain either a numerical value or NaN. Where a numerical value appears in one column, the corresponding cell in the other column will always be NaN, e.g.:

```
    A    B
0  123  NaN
1  456  NaN
2  NaN  789
```

I want to copy (or, alternatively, move) any non-NaN values in column A to overwrite the corresponding NaN in column B, e.g.:

```
    A    B
0  123  123
1  456  456
2  NaN  789
```

Based on [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15997670/1390080) to a similar question I have come up with:

```
mask = (df['A'] != np.nan)&(df['B'] == np.nan)
df['B'][mask] = df['A'][mask]
```

But this results in no change. Could anyone explain where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I've gone with jezrael's answer but would still value any clues as to why my (unnecessarily complicated, in this case) attempt failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df.B = df.B.combine_first(df.A)
print (df)
       A      B
0  123.0  123.0
1  456.0  456.0
2    NaN  789.0
```

Or:

```
df.B = df.B.fillna(df.A)
print (df)
       A      B
0  123.0  123.0
1  456.0  456.0
2    NaN  789.0
```

Anf if no `NaN` values in `B` after replacing cast to `int`:

```
df.B = df.B.fillna(df.A).astype(int)
print (df)
       A    B
0  123.0  123
1  456.0  456
2    NaN  789
```