# Copy columns values matching multiple columns patterns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I happen to have the following DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'Prod1':   ['10','','10','','',''],
                    'Prod2':   ['','5','5','','','5'],
                    'Prod3':   ['','','','8','8','8'],
                    'String1': ['','','','','',''],
                    'String2': ['','','','','',''],
                    'String3': ['','','','','',''],
                    'X1':      ['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5','x6'],
                    'X2':      ['','','y1','','','y2']
                    })
print(df)

  Prod1 Prod2 Prod3 String1 String2 String3  X1  X2
0    10                                      x1    
1           5                                x2    
2    10     5                                x3  y1
3                 8                          x4    
4                 8                          x5    
5           5     8                          x6  y2
```

It's a schematic table of Products with associated Strings; the actual Strings are in columns (`X1`, `X2`), but they should eventually move to (`String1`, `String2`, `String3`) based on whether the corresponding product has a value or not.

For instance:
row `0` has a value on `Prod1`, hence `x1` should move to `String1`.
row `1` has a value on `Prod2`, hence `x2` should move to `String2`.

In the actual dataset, mostly each `Prod` has a single `String`, but there are rows where multiple values are found in the Prods, and the String columns should be filled giving priority to the left. The final result should look like:

```py
  Prod1 Prod2 Prod3 String1 String2 String3 X1 X2
0    10                  x1                      
1           5                    x2              
2    10     5            x3      y1              
3                 8                      x4      
4                 8                      x5      
5           5     8              x6      y1
```

I was thinking about nested column/row loops, but I'm still not familiar enough with pandas to get to the solution.
Thank you very much in advance for any suggestion!

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: [Moving row values between columns based on other column values in a Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997430/moving-row-values-between-columns-based-on-other-column-values-in-a-pandas-dataf) ?

Comment: I saw that while researching for existing answers, but I haven't been able to fit it to my case (likely because of my current skill set) – I'm looking at Wen's reply now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I break down the steps :

```
df[['String1', 'String2', 'String3']]=(df[['Prod1', 'Prod2', 'Prod3']]!='')
df1=df[['String1', 'String2', 'String3']].replace({False:np.nan}).stack().to_frame()
df1[0]=df[['X1','X2']].replace({'':np.nan}).stack().values
df[['String1', 'String2', 'String3']]=df1[0].unstack()
df.replace({None:''})


Out[1036]: 
  Prod1 Prod2 Prod3 String1 String2 String3  X1  X2
0    10                  x1                  x1    
1           5                    x2          x2    
2    10     5            x3      y1          x3  y1
3                 8                      x4  x4    
4                 8                      x5  x5    
5           5     8              x6      y2  x6  y2
```

Comment: Thank you so much, brilliant use of `stack()` and `unstack()`.

Comment: @DavideBarranca Yw ~ Good night

Comment: As a side note, could you please explain, for the sake of my pandas understanding, why omitting the first `.to_frame()` at line 2 results in the `[x1, x2, x3, y1, x4, x5, x6, y2]` being put in the `df1` first row? Would there be a way, then, to modify the line 3 assignment to make it work anyway even without converting `df1` as a DataFrame? To be clear, your solution works like a charm, I'm playing with your code for learning purposes. Thank you!

Comment: @DavideBarranca the stack will give you `pd.Serise` , i just get used to work with `pd.Dataframe`, for your case you do not need `to_frame()`, but it is just like a habit, make it became `Dataframe`, in case we need add more para to the new `df`. *About why it being put in the first row*: `stack` will auto delete those `NaN`, That is why We need to replace those blanks to `np.nan`, `stack` will melt the data by index , x3 and y1 share the same index , that why it being put in the back of x3

Comment: I appreciate your time to explain that extra bits, thank you